# Submission of Scala code to a cluster

Tags: scala, cluster-computing, akka

Is it possible to run some akka code on the oracle grid engine with the use of multiple nodes?

So if I use the actor-model, which is a "message-passing model", is it possible to use Scala and the akka framework to run my code on a distributed memory system like a cluster or a grid?

If so, is there something similar like `mpirun` in `mpi -c`, to run my program on different nodes? Can you give a submission example using oracle grid engine?

how do I know inside scala on which node am I and to how many nodes the job has been submitted?

Is it possible to communicate with other nodes through the actor-model?

Comment: Avoid asking to many things in a single question.

Comment: i think it is not possible to communicate from one node to another using the actor model. for communication within nodes i have to use something like mpj express.

Comment: It is possible. Look at remote actors: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.3/scala/remoting.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mpirun` or (`mpiexec` on some systems) can run any kind of executables (even if they don't use MPI). I currently use it to launch java and scala codes on clusters. It may be tricky to pass arguments to the executable when calling `mpirun` so you could use an intermediate script.

We use Torque/Maui scripts which are not compatible with GridEngine, but here is a script my colleague is currently using:

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -l walltime=24:00:00
#PBS -l nodes=10:ppn=1
#PBS -l pmem=45gb
#PBS -q spc
# Find the list of nodes in the cluster
id=$PBS_JOBID
nodes_fn="${id}.nodes"
# Config file
config_fn="human_stability_article.conf"
# Java command to call
java_cmd="java -Xmx10g -cp akka/:EvoProteo-assembly-0.0.2.jar ch.unige.distrib.BuildTree ${nodes_fn} ${config_fn} ${id}"
# Create a small script to pass properly the parameters
aktor_fn="./${id}_aktor.sh"
echo -e "${java_cmd}" >> $aktor_fn
# Copy the machine file to the proper location
rm -f $nodes_fn
cp $PBS_NODEFILE $nodes_fn
# Launch the script on 10 notes
mpirun -np 10 sh $aktor_fn > "${id}_human_stability_out.txt"
```

Comment: thank you very much. how can i query the current node and the total node count inside scala?

Comment: @boraas I don't know how it works with GridEngine, but I use the machine file generated by torque/maui at submission. I attached a example.